# Помогите понять как работает рекурсивная функция

Tags: python, рекурсия

```
def reverse_str(string):
   if len(string) == 0:
       return ''
   else:
       return string[-1] + reverse_str(string[:-1])

reverse_str('test')  # tset
```

не совсем понимаю смысл строки `return string[-1] + reverse_str(string[:-1])`
`string[-1]` - последний элемент
`reverse_str(string[:-1])` - переворот строки же ?
так почему выражение переворота не работает без последнего элемента ?

Comment: `[:-1]` — не переворот, а все символы кроме последнего

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы понять, как работает рекурсивная функция, нужно понять из каких частей она состоит. Нормальная рекурсия состоит из 2 частей:

- Терминальное условие рекурсивной функции (условие остановки)
- Рекурсивный вызов

В вашем коде терминальное условие имеет следующий вид:

```py
if len(string) == 0:
       return ''
```

Его назначение - когда придет время, остановить рекурсию, чтобы она не выполнялась бесконечно долго.

Теперь перейдем к строчке с рекурсивному вызовом. Она состоит из следующего оператора:

```py
return string[-1] + reverse_str(string[:-1])
```

Отдельно разберем, что делает каждый операнд в этом операторе:

- `string[-1]` возвращает последний символ в переданной строке
- `string[:-1]` возвращает всю строку, за исключением последнего символа.

Второй операнд дополнительно передается в качестве аргумента этой же функции (это и называют рекурсивный вызовом). Теперь уже в ней будет находиться не вся строка, а только ее часть (без последнего символа). И так происходит до тех пор, пока строка не станет пустой. Тогда сработает терминальное условие и функция наконец-то вернет свое значение той функции, которая ее вызвала (а ее вызвала она же, ведь это рекурсия). Так просходит столько раз, сколько было вложенных вызовов. Этот процесс называется "раскрутка" рекурсии.

Приведу пошаговый результат выполнения на примере `reverse_str("test")`:

```
"t" + reverse_str("tes")
"t" + ("s" + reverse_str("te"))
"t" + ("s" + ("e" + reverse_str("t")))
"t" + ("s" + ("e" + ("t" + reverse_str("")))) <-- в этом месте рекурсия остановится и начнется раскручиваться в обратном направлении
"t" + ("s" + ("e" + ("t" + "")))
"t" + ("s" + ("e" + "t"))
"t" + ("s" + "et")
"t" + "set"
"tset"
```

Для более глубокого понимания рекурсии советую прочитать 3 главу книги "Грокаем Алгоритмы" Адитья Бхаргавы.